# Running Flutter on iOS build

Tags: flutter

[image]

Hi All,

Could anyone please help to sort the above issue in my flutter application. When I am running through the command line I am getting the above issue as per the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Firebase Console` > `Settings` > `Your Apps`

1. Create iOS app via "Add app" button
2. Download `GoogleService-Info.plist`
3. Place downloaded file in `<project_root>/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist`

Comment: Thanks I will try.

Comment: Hey @SwiftingDuster mate your solution worked. I was waiting for the .plist file. Thanks...